# Missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for a specific set of methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API project that runs in .NET 4.5. I enabled CORS functionality through the startup configuration. Everything in the API works except a few methods.

Whenever I call those methods using AJAX, preflight returns 200 but the actual call will return a CORS error. Those methods are expected to receive data in the form of a FormData and it has a file attached to it.

Upon looking at the responses, the preflight response has all the expected headers. However, the actual call does not even have Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

[preflight response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaFr4.png)

[POST response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWk6r.png)

I did everything to get at least Access-Control-Allow-Origin included in the response. I tried declaring UseCors() in Startup Configuration. I tried adding it to the WebApiConfig. I tried using a custom filter. I tried adding the header directly to the response in the method. I even tried explicitly defining it in the web.config. None of these seem to work.

What are the possible issues why a certain response header won't be in the response?

Thanks and advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the headers for OPTIONS methods (the CORS preflights).

We were able to achieve this by just setting it explicitly.

```cs
if(context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS") 
{
    context.Response.Headers.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000 https://localhost:8080");
}
```

Where context is an IOwinContext interface for Owin.